# Temporary data storage in android?

Tags: android

I want to get information from database only one time per day instead of hitting every time and i have to maintain that information like session.Currently i have planned to use Shared Preferences concept.Is it preparable?

Comment: SharedPreference value get exhausted when you clear application data

Comment: Any other better way is there in android?

Comment: In my knowledge "NO", there is only this much of storage options are only available.Refer this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: Is it local database inside app or Server side db?

Comment: it is local database

Comment: Even local database will be deleted when you clear data. So Shared preference is best for your case I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the option Sharedprefence is the best. But the valuse will be cleared when clearing the app data! 
so include some code to check the existance of sharedpreference values. if not existing, then restore them back by collecting data from your DB.. so you have to hit your DB rarely as user does it rarely!